# Hypothetical Pythagorean triple generator

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Let's say that I have a working Pythagorean triple generator for all integers greater or equal to 3. It generates primitive and non primitive pairs, and it's a one variable equation having to do with elements of the a term in a right triangle, not a case by case problem.  I would post it here, but I would like to get credit for making it, and am afraid someone will take it. If I have something like this, would others consider it useful, and if so, what should I do with it?

Comment: +1 for having the drive to work it out yourself. That said, I don't think there is much *new* credit left to claim about Pythagorean triples. See for example [Pythagorean Right-Angled Triangles](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html) for a quite extensive collection of Pythagorean calculators.

Comment: Wow... that is, indeed, a rather exhaustive collection D:

Comment: Should I just publish what I have come up with, and see if someone has already found this?

Comment: Barely related, you can generate a primitive Pythagorean triple for any given ratio $R=\frac{area}{perimeter}$ using Euclid's formula where $(m,n)=(2R+1,2R)$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: knowledge in mathematics is formally shared with the community through **publications**. You may be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275194/how-does-a-non-mathematician-go-about-publishing-a-proof-in-a-way-that-ensures-i?rq=1); and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898042/what-should-an-amateur-do-with-a-proof-of-an-open-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1), to a lesser extent.

Regarding credit: Unfortunately (for you), generating pythagorean triples— primitive or otherwise— is [a very well-studied problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples), and it's unlikely that what you have is new. [It maybe goes without saying, but for completeness: the Wikipedia page does not represent a comprehensive list of methods known for generating triples.]

At best, you may have an algorithmic improvement; that is, your method may be able to generate the first $n$ triples (ordered by norm or something) faster than other methods. But I couldn't find the state of the art on this kind of problem with a simple google result, and so you're not going to know  if this is the case for your method without (1) a serious analysis of your own method, and (2) a nontrivial literature search.

[ Or, of course, you could outsource that work (e.g. to MSE), but for that you would need to provide at least a technical description of your method, and it seems like you are not willing to do this. ]

Comment: FWIW: The set of pythagorean triples naturally forms a two-parameter family. But it is possible to write any two-parameter family as a one-parameter family, so this is not necessarily a guarantee of novelty.